# Conditional formating based on a previous day of a date in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a cell with a future date. I want to conditionally format the cell if I am one day before that date.

How I am going to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a formula to determine formatting, for example:

```
=$A$1=TODAY()-1
```